# scope of class properties in php

Tags: php, scope

I have a class which is instantiated globally and in turn instantiates a second class from within its constructor. What I can't figure out is how to gain access to properties of the first class from the second.

```
 <?php

    class Foo 
    { 
       public $bar;
       public $myProperty;
       public function __construct() 
       {
           $this->bar = new Bar();
           $this->myProperty='hello';
       }
    }

    class Bar 
    { 
       public function __construct() 
       {
           echo $foo->myProperty; //I can't see that from here
       }
    }

    $foo = new Foo(); 

   ?>
```

what might be the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem has nothing to do with scope of class properties, it's with scope of ordinary variables. `$foo` is a global variable, so it's not normally visible inside functions. You need to do:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    global $foo;
    echo $foo->myProperty;
}
```

However using global variables is usually bad form. It would be better if you passed `$foo` as a parameter to the `Bar` constructor.

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite regress. The `Foo` constructor creates `Bar`, and the `Bar` constructor tries to access the properties of `$foo`. But `$foo` won't have a value until the `Foo` constructor returns.

Comment: you use gobal keyword but its also won't work. What if I use $this instead of $foo???

Comment: Nothing will work. You're trying to access something before it's finished constructing.

Comment: agreed with @user2727841, use of global does not work, but I can pass itself into the constructor `$this->bar = new Bar($this);` I do prefer that. +1

Comment: But you won't be able to access `$foo->myProperty`, because the constructor doesn't assign that until _after_ it call `new Bar($this)`.

Comment: it seems to be ok provided that I assign `$this->myProperty` first

Comment: I think you should extends the class Foo to Bar